# Github private repositories and contributions

Tags: github

If I am contributing to multiple private repositories, maintained by different users, will they be able to see all my contributions in my profile in "Repositories contributed to" section or anywhere on my github profile page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private contributions aren’t public. Users can only see contributions to repositories they can access.

From GitHub's FAQ:

> Contributions to private repositories will only appear to users who
>   can access those repositories. Those contributions are not rendered
>   for users who cannot access those repositories.

https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/